# Asterisk GotoIf comparison variable exists in Array

Tags: asterisk

Currently I'm using the following condition:

```
exten => 1237,n,GotoIf($[ $[ "${text}" = "yes" ] | $[ "${text}" = "ok" ]  
| $[ "${text}" = "perfect" ] ]?interest:retry)
```

Is it a better way to define this syntax, I would like to compare the value of text against an array of strings, but I cant find a way to do it. Example:

```
exten => 1237,n,GotoIf($[ $[ "${text}" in ARRAY("yes","ok","perfect") ]  ]?interest:retry)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of `in` operator in Asterisk, but you can use regex match instead:

```
GotoIf($[ "${text}" =~ "^(yes|no|perfect)$"]?interest:retry)
```

Comment: Nice. But better always add quotes(changed).

Answer (score 0):

[FIELDNUM](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Function_FIELDNUM) Is almost what you need

```
exten = 1237,n,Set(STRARRAY='yes-ok-perfect')
exten = 1237,n,GotoIF($[ ${FIELDNUM(STRARRAY,-,${text})} > 0 ]?interest:retry)
```